# Dialling with favorites

Tags: contacts, phone-app

With My old phone as soon as I hit my favorites button, the phone would automatically dial the number that I set as a default.  With this phone, when I hit an entry on my favorites list, it brings me to a list of numbers and I have to choose a number.  HOw can I program  the phone to automatically dial a favorite number? I tried setting a number as a default and it doesn't work.

Comment: which Android version?

Answer (score 2):

in ICS, if you use the Favorites tab in the **People** app, then it will behave like you mentioned; however if you use the Favorites tab in the **Phone** app, then it will directly call the number you set as default number for the contact.